# DateTimePicker Value Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, datetimepicker

I have a DateTimePicker with custom format `'LT'`. When I get the value, I get `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format instead of ISO-8601.

```
$('#init').datetimepicker({
   format: 'LT',
   ...
});


var init = $('#init').data("DateTimePicker").viewDate().format();
console.log(init); // Shows 'YYYY-MM-DD' and I want ISO-8601
```

If I don't format the `init` variable, I get a moment object with these values:

```
init {
_ambigTime: true
_ambigZone: true
_d: Wed Mar 20 2019 10:15:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
_f: "YYYY-MM-DD"
_fullCalendar: true
_i: "2019-03-20"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
... }
```

I don't know why it has `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format declared.

Thanks in advance!

**-- EDIT:**

1. I'm using [Eonasdan/Bootstrap-DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)
2. I tried to cast the `init` variable with `.toISOString()` and I still get `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: Which specific jQuery datetimepicker are you using? It's likely it doesn't support the LT locale.

Comment: I don't understand the question - YYYY-MM-DD looks pretty much like ISO-8601 to me....

Comment: It might also be worth specifying what extention you use as `datetimepicker` since jQueryUI only offers `datepicker`. Furthermore *datepicker* doesn't support a *format* option. It does support the options *altFormat*, *dateFormat* and *navigationAsDateFormat* with a quick search through the [public API](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm using [Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), with `LT` (time only) and `inline` format, just to set the time of an event. I want the ISO-8601 to save it on the data base. Documentation only says that `viewDate` [function](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#viewdate) "Returns a moment variable"

Answer (score -1):

It fixed parsing to UTC:
`$('#init').data("DateTimePicker").viewDate().utc().format()`